# Add tags to <head> reliably in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom, iframe

I am writing a program that does the following:

- Creates an iframe in the DOM
- Makes an AJAX request to a page (a site's main page)
- If the page has changed, I use `iframe.srcdoc = contents;` to the iframe, where `contents` is what came back from AJAX

Note that this way any image etc. with a relative URL specified will not render correctly. To make it look right, I have to add a `<base>` tag to `<head>`.

I am *very* reluctant to use regexp like this:

```
contents = contents.replace('<head>','<head><base href="http://www.example.com/">');
```

Because it might stuff things up (but, am I being way too overcautious and over-paranoid?).

**NOTE**: I cannot do this by manipulating DOM: if I do `iframe.srcdoc = contents;` and *then* add the `<base>` tag, the page will still render incorrectly. The `<base>` tag needs to be there *before* I assign it to `iframe.srcdoc`...

How would you go about this?

Merc.

Comment: Why don't you just set the iframe's source to the URL of the page?

Comment: @barmar for _speed_. Chrome only provides a 'load' event once te HOLE thing is loaded, scripts etc., whereas I need to check the contents as soon as the main page arrives.

Answer (score 2):

Use `appendChild` DOM operation to add the element.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild('<base href="http://www.site.com" />');
```

Comment: I wish... I cannot do this by manipulating DOM: if I do `iframe.srcdoc = contents;` and _then_ add the `<base>` tag, the page will still render incorrectly. The `<base>` tag needs to be there _before_ I assign it to `iframe.srcdoc`...

Comment: I see. Given `contents` is just text at that stage, just use the replace then.

Answer (score 1):

In my holy opinion using `appendChild` with string-values it not the best idea, so here is my approach.

```
// create new "base"-node
var node = document.createElement('base');
// set href="http://www.site.com"
node.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.site.com');
// append new "base"-node to first "head"-node in html-document
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
```

see [W3-School The HTML DOM (Document Object Model)](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) for details about DOM-Manipulation, DOM-Understanding and Javascript-Reference.

Solution for inject "base"-tag with string-manipuation (kind of "non-dom-offline") is Regex to prepend base-tag before closing head-tag.

```
contents = contents.replace(/<\/head>/ig, '<base href="http://www.site.com" />$&');
```

An other solution can is using jQuery to construct an "offline-DOM" of the contents of the iframe and using DOM-Manipulation-Methods.

```
contents = jQuery(contents).find('head:first').append('<base ... />').html()
// no guarantee here that this will work ;-) it was just out of my mind, but should work.
```

Comment: My question wasn't clear enough, sorry... I cannot do this by manipulating DOM: if I do `iframe.srcdoc = contents;` and _then_ add the `<base>` tag, the page will still render incorrectly. The `<base>` tag needs to be there _before_ I assign it to `iframe.srcdoc`...